# How to use the Drive API to upload huge files via URI?

Tags: google-drive-api, uri

I've been trying to upload huge files to Google Drive but so many errors are constantly occuring and it's just a huge pain in the ass to find files that have and haven't been uploaded to the drive before the errors.

Here is the link I need help understanding:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/resumable-upload

I have no background in programming or developing so I'd be very grateful for some explanation that's easy to understand.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This site is for people to share their code that they are having difficulty with. People share some code and ask for advice on how to make it work. It's not a site for general concept training.

Comment: @Alan, thanks for letting me know.